# RDP Saved credentials problem, how disable Windows Defender Credential Guard

Tags: windows, rdp, windows-defender

After Windows updates, there is occurred saved credentials problem, rdp always asks password, cannot be saved.. The reason is Windows Defender Credential Guard.
How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

Solution from Microsoft Learn (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-manage):

Start Local Group Policy Editor

[Edit group policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TTdo.png)

Navigate to Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Guard > Turn on Virtualization Based Security. In the "Credential Guard Configuration" section, set the dropdown value to "Disabled":

[Local Group Policy Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VqKm.png)

Comment: It works for me: Windows 11 Pro, 22H2

Comment: Works after a reboot.

Comment: Be careful with solutions like this. It's like someone is having network problems and you recommend disabling the firewall instead of configuring ports/ip.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is here,

```
    > Open registry editor (regedit)
    > Find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa.  
    > Add a new DWORD value named LsaCfgFlags. and set it to 0 to 
      disable it.
    > Close registry editor and restart the system.
```

If anyone knows another way, please add it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

**Starting in Windows 11, version 22H2, Credential Guard is turned on by default** on devices that meet the requirements. The default enablement is without UEFI Lock. [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/configure?tabs=intune#default-enablement)

When Credential Guard is enabled, the RDP connections do not allow to use of the password saved on Windows.

When you try connecting to a host using RDP, you will receive a message *"Windows Defender Credential Guard does not allow using saved credentials."* and will prompt you to insert the user credentials.

If Credential Guard is enabled without UEFI Lock and without Group Policy (the default), it's sufficient to edit the registry keys to disable it.

**Solution**
-Add (create if necessary) these two Windows Registry keys on the client RDP machine (the machine that you want to connect to an RDP server):

```
Key path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
Key name: LsaCfgFlags
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0

Key path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard
Key name: LsaCfgFlags
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0
```

It is possible to create a registry file with the keys.
To do that simply save the text below on a .reg file and run it on the client machine.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceGuard] 
"LsaCfgFlags"=dword:00000000 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa] 
"LsaCfgFlags"=dword:00000000
```

**Restart the device to apply the change.**

Some links:
[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/configure?tabs=reg#disable-credential-guard)
[Microsoft answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-disable-windows-11-defender-credential/8ed83adc-56e9-4b6a-ac79-39803bbdfb07)